$templateProcessor->deleteBlock('mostCompetitive'); is not working in phpWord in Laravel
I am using PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor to modify my template DOCX document and its setValue method works well.
but I am not sure how to use $templateProcessor->deleteBlock();
Here is my template docx.
${most_competitive}
    This bank has the most competitive PDH Green 10 Year Fixed rate mortgage in the market.
${/most_competitive}

and I tried to delete this block "most_competitive" in some cases.
Here is my php code
$filePath = resource_path("template-docx/Template.docx");
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($filePath);
...
if(true) { // TODO
    $templateProcessor->deleteBlock('is_changing_term');
}
...
$fileName = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4() . ".docx";
$templateProcessor->saveAs(storage_path($fileName));

But it doesn't work at all.
I tried to use replaceBlock, or cloneBlock instead, but all of them didn't work.
How to solve this issue?
Please let me know the solution.
Welcome any suggestions or hints.
Thanks in advance.
